# VLC can't read DVDs even after I installed things to read them

Tags: 13.10, vlc, 32-bit, dvd

Moment ago and I got this from VLC media player

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/dvd".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/dvd'. Check the log for details.
```

I typed this command to enable DVD playback, It worked on my desktop with Ubuntu 13.10

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321 && sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the VLC logfiles like the error says to, to find details of why it couldn't read it?

Comment: I thought the log file would display exactly what I just copied and pasted. I guess I will find the file and read it. thanks

Comment: I don't know where the log file is, I am still new to Ubuntu it's not like windows where I can check C:\Program files\VLC. I am lost in this OS, I am not sure where anything is yet. It's still better than Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same thing with my rarely used dvd drive today. Apparently the symlink to the block device was missing. After inspecting `dmesg` I found it is sr0 in my case.

So:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/dvd
```

fixed it for me.

PS: Try `man dmesg`, `man sudo`, `man ln`, if you do not understand this. The first few years of linux is all about reading man pages, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VLC in xubuntu 13.10 and all i did was copy and paste the location of the disc in the file manager.

Then opened up the VLC application-click on "File"-"Open Disc"-under the "Disc" tab.

Copied and pasted the location URL (where it says /dev/dvd) or browse for the location, then open or play. It worked for me.